# WCF to SharePoint 2013 - Token for User not WCF Application ID

Tags: wcf, sharepoint-2013, token, wcf-security

We're using a WCF service to connect to SharePoint 2013 for updating lists.

We create a client token on our web page which calls the WCF service and our issue is that updates are logged in SharePoint as being by the "WCF Application ID" (the identity the WCF App Pool is logged in as) instead of the person's user ID.

Has anyone ever encountered this issue? I can provide the token creation code if it helps.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Have you tried using impersonation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731090%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our issue was we were creating the app context and not a user context. We had to create a user token instead.